# React prevent child component from re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Lists` component that holds many lists and its render function looks like:

```js
var items = this.props.items;
  var lists = this.props.lists;
  var addItem = this.props.addItem;
  return (
    <div key={uuidv4()}>
    {lists.map(function(listName) {
      return (
        <List name={listName} items={items[listName]} addItem={addItem.bind(this)} key={uuidv4()} />
      )
    })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My problem is that when I add an item to a certain list, every list re-renders even though their props haven't changed. I have tried using `shouldComponentUpdate` in my List component:

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.props.items !== nextProps.items;
}
```

But it does not stop the lists from re-rendering. `PureComponent` doesn't seem to work either. Is there a better way to structure my code so that these unnecessary renders are avoided?

EDIT: Here is the code that handles adding an item. Note that the `s` is the state of a list:

```
handleAddItem(s) {
      let listName = s.name;
      let newlist = this.state.items[listName];

      newlist.push({name: [s.newItem]});
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        items: {
          ...prevState.items,
          [listName]: newlist
        }
      }));
  }
```

It is in my `App` component, which renders the `Lists` component:

```
<Lists lists={this.state.lists} items={this.state.items} addItem={this.handleAddItem.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: This might be due to your equality check in shouldComponentUpdate -> perhaps check the equality of the size of this.props.items or some other quality that would be unique until changed (items added or removed)

Comment: Can you show us how you add items to the list?

Comment: The equality check you're doing is the problem with this, but how you're creating keys also isn't helping. Keys need to stay the same throughout multiple renders, but doing this `key={uuidv4()` is creating a new key each render. This will also lead to multiple renders since the key is changing. You should assign the uuid's to the item or list on creation, and read it from there. Or if listName is unique, use that

Comment: @FujiRoyale I changed it to `this.props.items.length !== nextProps.items.length` but now it's always returning false. The console shows that this.props.items and nextProps.items holds the same values after I insert.

Comment: @webdevdani I changed the keys to the list names and updated my equality check but now shouldComponentUpdate is always returning false.

Comment: @counterhash, could you share the code where you're adding the items to the object?

Comment: @webdevdani okay, i added the code to my post.

Comment: @counterhash: Why did you add `shouldComponentUpdate` in the first place? Unless you actually noticed a performance problem, I would just remove it, since it's probably unnecessary. It's ok for `render` to be called again, and doesn't necessarily mean that DOM nodes are being updated, which is where a user would usually experience a performance issue.

Comment: @ericgio Yes it isn't necessary for this program, but I wanted to try removing unnecessary renders for fun. Also, DOM nodes aren't always updated when render is called? I did not know that

Comment: @counterhash They're only redrawn if there are changes between the shadow DOM version that render creates and then compares to what's currently in the DOM. (But if your keys change between render calls, it will redraw them since it has nothing to compare against anymore)